# How are Imperial Star Destroyers driven?

Tags: star-wars

In the films  we see officers shouting orders into pits on the bridge but those guys are pressing buttons and scribbling things down on paper, is there any order to their button pressing ? Is there any descriptions of their driving mechanism in star wars?

Comment: These guys are doing the flying; http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/b/b8/Venator_bridge.png/revision/latest?cb=20130208040241

Comment: How are Imperial star destroyers driven?  Very well thanks!

Comment: Probably a stick shift - Can't imagine the Imps would use automatic transmission

Answer (score 2):

There are not any novels that go into that kind of details. On ISDs, there is a bank of navigational officers in those crew pits that handle the actual maneuvering and working the navigational computers for hyperspace jumps.

The closest reference would be Star Wars III, where "The Invisible Hand" was dropping out of orbit over Corusant, you see Anakin jump into a station, where he is probably calling on the computer to fire whatever maneuvering thrusters and then later deploying air brakes. That will probably be the closest you will get, a scene with Christiansen Hayden trying to 'pilot' half a space capital ship, that somehow has air brakes when other sources have shown large ships to have repulsors.